# Images load in all browsers but not in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, html, asp.net-mvc, uiwebview

I have a website that is set up as an application underneath another site on my server. all the javascript, css, and image files are set as relative paths. When I had the site as it's own top level site everything worked in all browsers as well as in the mobile app I created that contains a UIWebview.

When I moved the site as an IIS application underneath another site of mine everything that was set as src= stopped working. I went through and adjusted the HTML to load the Request.FilePath (virtual Path) for all of these and everything started working again...except in the UIWebview of my app. Has anyone run into this before and why does this happen? the site works fine if I open safari on my phone.

HTML

```
    <% string rootPath = Request.FilePath; %>
    <img src="<%= rootPath %>/Resources/image.png" />
```

Source

```
    <img src="/WMS/Resources/image.png">
```

Once again this is working in all browsers (IE, FF, Safari) but when I open it up in a UIWebView the image doesn't load

I'm using .NET 4, IIS7, MVC2, iPhone 4 with the latest SDK

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you post the actual src? i.e. "/static/Resources/image.png"

Comment: Edited based on Josh's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too, I've fixed it by using Url.Content. try something like this:
`src="<%= Url.Content("~/Resources/image.png") %>"`

Comment: Wow...this had me completely stumped but this is working now, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: I would also like to point out that the source for this solutions results to the exact same source that I posted in the question

Answer (score 1):

Three things come to mind:

1. Caching - UIWebView's cache is to the broken link?
2. IIS is serving static files with improper MIME types?
3. (I'm reaching here) Is your mobile test device on the same network / domain?

Comment: Thanks for your response. it's not a caching issue, I always clear the cache before I run another test in the app. the MIME types are all set properly (all the images are .png) and I tested the app out both not connected to the network and connected to the network and both produce the same results. the UIWebview doesn't have any issues loading the images when the site is setup in IIS as it's own site but fails when moved underneath another site and set as an application.